# How to access PPTP/L2TP Protocol in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, networkextension, nevpnmanager

I trying to implement custom vpn protocol for inside app to access odata api url. In my office they are using PPTP/L2TP protocol. Is there anyway to achieve this.

Any help much appreciated pls..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Network Extension framework's NEPacketTunnelProvider to develop custom VPN protocol. But I would suggest you to enable IPSec protocol on your VPN server and use NEVPNMANAGER instead using NEVPNProtocolIPSEC.